# Multivariable calculus about divagence operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus

if $\mathbf{r} = (x, y, z)$ be the vector that points from the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the point $(x,y,z)≠(0,0,0)$,

> Is there a $p > 0$ such that 
>   $$\mathrm{div} \big(\mathbf{r} / (\| \mathbf{r} \|^p)\big)= 0?$$

${d\over dx} ({r\over(|r|^p)})+{d\over dy}({r\over(|r|^p)})+{d\over dz}({r\over(|r|^p)}) = div ({r\over (|r|^p)})$
How can I suppose to find p or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by just simply expand the term $\frac{\mathbf{r}}{||r||^p}$:
$$\frac{\mathbf{r}}{||\mathbf{r}||^p}=\left(\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{p/2}},\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{p/2}},\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{p/2}}\right)$$

$$\mathrm{div}\left(\frac{\mathbf{r}}{||\mathbf{r}||^p}\right)=\nabla\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{||\mathbf{r}||^p}$$$$=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{p/2}},\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{p/2}},\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{p/2}}\right)$$

I give you the first term
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{p/2}}=\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2}-x^2p(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2-1}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^p}$$

for the other terms are similar. Now set it into zero and the denominator vanish, becoming:

$$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2}-x^2p(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2-1}-y^2p(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2-1}-z^2p(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2-1}=0$$

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2-1}(3-p)(x^2+y^2+z^2)=0$$

since $x^2+y^2+z^2>0$, $p=3$ would be the answer.